# how to remove notice in php of checkbox?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

When I submit form without selecting `input type=check box`, the NOTICE will appear so please tell me how to avoid it? I ask it because when I do with `input type=text`, the NOTICE doesn't appear.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo $_POST['check'];
}
?>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="check box" name="check" value="1">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

empty() checks variable is set or not and also it has any value both...

```
  <?php

    if(!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
       echo  $checkbox_value = !empty($_POST['check'])?$_POST['check']:'--';
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your Welcome Dear Enjoy...:)